# Apple build rejected due to IPv6 Issue

Tags: ios, alamofire, ipv6, reachability

Recently I have submitted the app to App store and it got rejected due to IPv6 not supported.

I checked online [ready.chair6.net](http://ready.chair6.net/) and it shows that ***Hostname does not have IPv6 AAAA record.***

So my question is, Once we do changes on our server, do I need to change anything in my code?

I'm Using **Alamofire** v3.5.1 for API calls, and **[Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)** class to check the Internet connectivity.

Also how to make make sure that my app is running fine on IPv6? I have seen on Apple developer site for ***[How to create IPv6 virtually on your mac?](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html)***

I successfully able to configure that but when I connect my device to the same network and I check the IP address in the device it shows IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. But again not sure its using IPv4 or IPv6?

Answer (score 0):

Updating your Alamofire v3.5.1 to Alamofire v4.0 will solve the problem. If you want to do it manually without any library use URLSession. You don't need to create any virtual IPV6.

Comment: Alamofire v4.0 requires Swift 3.0 and my code is in Swift 2.3 So it is necessary to update to the Alamofire v4.0?

Comment: @milanpanchal Then you must also update to Swift 3.0.